# I Need to Ask a Poll-Type Question

Tags: discussion

I am trying to find out the pronunciation of a computer term, but since it is (mostly) a poll-type question, I figured I would ask for advice first in order to avoid getting raped by the seemingly ever-increasing aggressive people on the SE sites. `:-|`

What I wanted to do was to simulate a poll by posting the question (I’m not sure whether it is more appropriate here or on the English site), about how the computer term should be pronounced and give a bit of explanation about the two main pronunciations—both have their merits. (I considered clicking *community wiki* as well, but that is no longer available by default.)

Then I was going to post both of the pronunciations as answers so that people can vote for the pronunciation they use. I also considered posting the two main pronunciations as comments to the main question, particularly since it prevents people from down-voting the one they don’t use; posting them as answers relies on the honesty of users.

The assumption is that after a decent number of votes, a relatively clear picture of what the more popular (and thus de facto “correct”) pronunciation is, while still allowing for the possibility of someone giving an answer/link about a possible de jure answer.

(In one of the discussions about polls on Meta, someone suggested that polls belong on `pollmnkey.com`—which for the record is blocked by the anti-ad section of my HOSTS file. If that is considered correct, then wouldn’t posting the question there and then posting a link to that poll on a StackExchange site not be extraneous and redundant? Worse, wouldn’t that make it difficult to form a valid SE question since there is no actual answer? Besides, who wants to register *yet another* account on *yet another* site, especially one that would be used infrequently?)

So now I’ve got two questions (in addition to the original question, um…, in question):

1. Would such a question be more appropriate for `SuperUser` or `English`?
2. Would I/my rep get killed for asking it and/or the question get shut down, leaving me scratching my head with a still-unanswered question?
3. Should I use a third-party site instead, and if so, how do I get people to vote on it?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: How a computer term is pronounced. Technically it is a computer question, but not specifically about hardware or software. I suppose it could be considered a language question (and there are other pronunciation questions on English, though they are mostly non-computer related).

Comment: It's not GIF is it?

Comment: @random, GIF already has entire pages dedicated to it: http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=pronounce+gif (and I have always said jif; gif sounds too soft and mushy—which for the record is correct according to CompuServe, so Mac users are wrong).

Comment: That's what we have chat for @Synetech

Comment: -1 for asking for advice before asking a question‽ Really? I can understand a down-vote for the question itself, but for asking ahead?

Comment: No. Downvote = "No to polls"

Comment: No. No you don't. If you have a poll goto poll.com or something. We're a Q&A site.

Comment: @drachenstern, *“no. no you don’t”*? It would be clearer if you quoted the specific question.

Comment: @Synetech ~ `I Need to Ask a Poll-Type Question`

Comment: I don’t? I could have sworn I did. I thought I had to go to the bathroom too, but maybe I don’t…

Answer (score 8):

Poll type questions are ill advised for any of the Stack Exchange set of sites.

For pronunciation, your hypothetical question is better for English Language & Usage [as their FAQ states](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) the following territory:

> The [English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> Usage, word choice, and grammar
> [...]
> **Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)** [...]

If you posted the question on Super User it would be closed as off topic.

Not sure how EL&U would handle it. Though, if it was made into a poll, would most likely suffer the same fate as here.

If you need eyeballs on it, you could ask the people who hang out in chat.

Answer (score 7):

I am racking my brain, but I can't think of any way ...

> How do I pronounce [this computer term]?

.. would be on topic for Super User even a little.

Comment: A computer term is part of computer software/hardware isn’t it? Especially if it is something that can be answered from documentation/specifications.

Comment: Pronunciation isn't a computer problem. It's a language hurdle/quirk/game. @syn

Comment: No, but then lots of stuff can be relegated to other sites. It’s a matter of multiple categories; eg does a video-editing program go in the video folder or the editors folder? Does an Ubuntu question go on SuperUser or on Ubuntu? Does an encryption algorithm go in StackOverflow or Math? A JavaScript question go on StackOverflow or Programmers or Webmasters or DocType? It’s really about *more fitting*, which I guess is now clear in this case.

Comment: @Synetech Have you considered asking the question on [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com). I recently migrated a similar style question there without issues.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m going to do. (I assume you are talking about the one asking how to pronounce AJAX, right?)

Comment: @Synetech Yeah. That was the one.